# thread stops too soon

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, parallel-processing

I'm trying to make a script which does two parallel things:

1. One thread: Requesting a server and appending responses into RESPONSES variable (list) in a `Pool`
2. Second thread: Processing responses from RESPONSES list

It seems that it works but it stops before all products are processed. For example 70 products are done but 30 remains.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
from threading import Thread
import requests

RESPONSES = []
POOL_IS_ALIVE = True

with open('products.txt') as f:
    LINES = f.readlines()[:100]

def post_request(url):
    html = requests.get(url).content
    RESPONSES.append(html)


def parse_product(html, url):
    # long code which returns instance of class product

def start_requesting(): # Creates a pool with 100 workers
    pool = Pool(100)

    for n,line in enumerate(LINES):
        pool.apply_async(post_request, args=(line[:-1],))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

t1 = Thread(target=start_requesting)

def process_responses():
    i=0
    db = db_manager.db_manager()

    while True:
        try:
            response = RESPONSES.pop()
        except IndexError:
            continue

        product = parse_product(response,'url')
        db.insert_product(product)

        if not t1.is_alive():
            print 'IS_ALIVE NOT'
            break


t2 = Thread(target=process_responses)

now = datetime.now()

t1.start()
t2.start()
t2.join() # MAYBE HERE IS THE PROBLEM
t1.join()


print now-datetime.now()
```

Where could be the problem?

Comment: why are you joining on `t2` first ? it seems more logical to wait for `t1` completion, then `t2` ?

Answer (score 4):

First, there's some error in your code:

```
if not t.is_alive():
    print 'IS_ALIVE NOT'
    break
```

there's no variable "t" at all, haven't you got an error like "`NameError: name 't' is not defined`"?

Second, just print the step of your program, and see in what step run out of expected. or you can use python debugger [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

Third,

```
RESPONSES = []
```

`RESPONSE` is thread safe, but just as @mguijarr mentioned, use [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) is better.

Comment: `RESPONSE` is a list, and in CPython appending to a list **is** thread-safe because it turns out it is an atomic operation (thanks to GIL), it is also safe to just get an item from a list e.g. `RESPONSE[i]`. Counting on atomicity is a dangerous game but it can be useful sometimes.

Comment: @mguijarr and monklof: So what's better guys? Should I use Queue? I use pure Python 2.7, not CPython. Thanks

Comment: CPython is the C implementation of Python, so it corresponds to Python 2.7 or 3.x... My explanation on atomic operations is valid in your case - your code seems ok in term of thread safety to me but `Queue` is better because it has been designed to share data between threads at the price of mutexes.